# When resize the container text not stay in center in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-text, flutter-container

here when the drag the container the text is not center if some height and width get than container text set in center.

```dart
double width = 110.0;
double height = 40.0;
double fontSize = 14;
bool _isSelected = true;
```

```dart
child: Container(
    height: height,
    width: width,

    decoration: _isSelected ? BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      border: Border.all(
        width: 2,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ) : null,
  
    child: Center(
      child: TextField(
        key: textFieldKey,
        controller: textController,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: fontSize),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          fillColor: Colors.black,
            hintText: "Enter Your Text",
            helperStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            border: InputBorder.none
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        onSubmitted: (text){
          setState(() {
            _isSelected = false;
          });
        },
    ),
  ),
),
```

This is drag icon functionality.

```dart
if(_isSelected)
  Positioned(
    top: top - ballDiameter / 2,
    left: left - ballDiameter / 2,
    child: ManipulatingBall(
      onDrag: (dx, dy) {
        var newWidth = width - (2*dx);
        var newHeight = height - (2*dx/aspectRatio);
        setState(() {
          fontSize = height / 3.57*1.5;
          print("height = $height");
          print("width = $width");
          print("fontsize = $fontSize");

          if(newHeight > 10 && newWidth > 10)
          {
            height = newHeight;
            width = newWidth;
            top = top + (dx/aspectRatio);
            left = left + dx;
          }

        });
      },
      handlerWidget: HandlerWidget.VERTICAL,
    ),
  ),
```

i add the image in this image text show on top of container not set center.
[image: here add image in below]

what wrong in this code.

Comment: Please create a gist of your complete code and post a link in the comments.

Comment: most likely this is `TextField` "fault", try just for test to replace it with `Text` and check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect the text inside `TextField` to stay centered if the `Container`'s height is too small for the `TextField`. Here's an illustration:

If I you put `height: 20` to the `Container`, you will see this in the UI:

[image]

If you go to [DevTools](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/overview) and [enable guidelines](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/inspector#show-guidelines), you'll notice this:

[image]

The `TextField` does not fit inside the `Container`, which make the text not centered.

If you give enough height for the `TextField`, for example by giving `height: 40` to the `Container`, you'll get this:

[image]

[image]

It fits inside the `Container`, so it's now perfectly centered. You can try increasing the height and no matter how big the value is, the text will stay centered.

---

To fix it, you can give a limit on the minimum value for the `Container`'s height so that `TextField` will always fit.

Comment: any solution i have to textfiled fit in to the container. container is resizable when container size increase same as textfiled size increase both border of container and testfiled same for all event.